# How do I switch between two notebooks in Mathematica 9 interface?

Tags: notebooks, windows

How do I switch between two notebook windows in the *Mathematica 9* interface?

I would like to use a keyboard shortcut such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Tab</kbd> as with windows or tabs in programs like  *Firefox*.

Comment: Don't forget your two notebooks will be sharing the same kernel.  If you do a=1 in one notebook, a will equal 1 in the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac, the default is usually <kbd>CMD</kbd> +  <kbd>`</kbd> . You can remap the keyboard shortcuts via the links in Öskå's comment above.

FWIW, you can also create your own palette using the [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Button.html?q=Button&lang=en) command and then install it in Mathematica via the Palette menu; this is useful if you have a variety of actions you want to take, for example, rearranging / resizing windows, restyling cells, ...

Comment: Does this still work in Mathematica 12? None of the open windows show up for me in the window picker. Only 'messages', if there is an error message.